# Dependency installation error. how to fix it?

Tags: nearprotocol

So I followed the docs, and got this error while installing dependencies, is it because of my node version?

I installed node using NVM
I installed yarn using npm
Near works perfectly for me

```
Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./build.js
Arguments:
Directory: /mnt/c/Users/KIIT/react/Near/counter/node_modules/deasync
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
gyp info using node@17.6.0 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/home/priyansu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:33)
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/priyansu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:22       
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/priyansu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5        
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/priyansu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
gyp ERR! command "/home/priyansu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.6.0/bin/node" "/home/priyansu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/KIIT/react/Near/counter/node_modules/deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v17.6.0
```

Comment: What are you trying to install? Is it from an existing project? I think we need some more information to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

the docs you are talking about is the [counter example](https://examples.near.org/counter#login)
I think it is related to your node version.
So try to downgrade it to a lower version mine is v14.17.6 which the example is working on it.